# Azure WebJobs and Service Bus : 2 settings for the same thing?

Tags: azure-webjobs

When I add the following NuGet package to my WebJob: `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus 2.0.0`, 
two new items are added to the `app.config` file.
It seems they are both used to define the Service Bus connection string.
Can I get rid of one of them?

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="AzureWebJobsServiceBus" connectionString="..." />
</connectionStrings>

<appSettings>
  <!-- Service Bus specific app setings for messaging connections -->
  <add key="Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConnectionString" value="..." />
</appSettings>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: How do you configure your jobhost ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It seems they are both used to define the Service Bus connection string. Can I get rid of one of them?

According the source code of [ServiceBusConfiguration](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus/Config/ServiceBusConfiguration.cs), WebJob Service Bus SDK(ServiceBusTrigger) will use the connection string which stored under the connectionStrings section.

```
public string ConnectionString
{
    get
    {
        if (!_connectionStringSet)
        {
            _connectionString = AmbientConnectionStringProvider.Instance.GetConnectionString(ConnectionStringNames.ServiceBus);
            _connectionStringSet = true;
        }
        return _connectionString;
    }
    set
    {
        _connectionString = value;
        _connectionStringSet = true;
    }
}
```

You can also set the connection string at runtime.

```
JobHostConfiguration config = new JobHostConfiguration();
config.UseServiceBus(new ServiceBusConfiguration() { ConnectionString = "" });
JobHost host = new JobHost(config);
```

If you want to create a instance of Service Bus Client(for example QueueClient) to do some specific operations, you could use the Service Bus connection string configured in appSettings.

```
//Use CloudConfigurationManager to read the connection string stored in appSettings
string connectionString = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConnectionString");
var client = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, "queueName");
```